# D3.js line chart, x axis have arbitrary dates, but want to show them sequental

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a line chart. x axis have dates, but they are not distributed noramally (no data for lunch or weekends), but I want to show them sequential.
Sample data and my sample graph is below, I don't want my graph to show straight line for time which has no data, it should continue from previous date.

I use `x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width])` to draw x line.
Any idea?

```
x         y
10:00:00  4
10:10:00  5
10:20:00  3
10:30:00  2
10:40:00  5
10:50:00  3
14:30:00  6
14:40:00  7
```

[image]

Comment: do you want to skip dates where you don't have data ?

Comment: Well in that case I think you need to you `d3.scale.ordinal()` instead of `d3.time.scale()`

Comment: Yes, want to skip dates which has no data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `ordinal scale` would do the trick. Try something like this:

Replace `x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width])` with below :

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.date;
    }))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. When I add this, .ticks() function doesn't work. My function is      xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("right").ticks(5).tickFormat(d3.time.format(dateFormat))

Comment: ticks() function is to divide the axis labels as per the range for example ticks(5) would divide the range into 5 and specify the labels but it wont affect the scale i.e. your scale will still be the range between start and end date and everything in between if you use time scale.

Comment: I believe this would cause every other x value to be displayed: `xAxis.tickValues(x.domain().filter(function(d, i) { return !(i % 2); }));`
Source: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3212294

Comment: @wilburrr90 I agree with you. Moreover I believe removing  ticks() all together  from x will result to display of all x values.

Comment: @wilburrr90 using tickValues solved my problem. Thank you all.